# Invest in an US ETF or fund being a UK citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, etf, mutual-funds, regulation, foreign-currency

Is it possible to invest in a US ETF or fund being a UK citizen, without having any sort of bank or brokerage account based in the USA?

I'm not talking about these ETFs / funds that hold US assets but are sold in pounds sterling, I mean investing in a product whose underlying currency is US dollars, so at the moment of selling it you would receive the cash in the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A U.S. account requires U.S. residency.

Just invest in U.S. securities through a European account that offers international investing. Then buy currency ETF's, or buy currency futures, or take Forex positions, for whatever amount of dollar positions are to be held.

Comment: Someone foreign to the U.S. can easily invest in a U.S. private corporation that is not a pass-through company. That's an odd point to make but I have a corporation like that. Or someone foreign to the U.S. can create a U.S. LLC non-issuer company that holds a brokerage account. However, the LLC must file U.S. tax forms and then possibly the owner could also owe home country taxes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can no longer buy US domiciled ETFs that don't comply with EU regulations, which most don't do.  I'm not sure how will change because of Brexit.

Here's a good [overview of the problem](https://www.justetf.com/uk/news/etf/us-domiciled-etfs.html).

Comment: The actual best reason to invest internationally is to take positions in individual stocks of interest. And actually, a U.S. account, for instance, that invests directly in other countries does convert-to and hold foreign currencies. But many investors in the U.S. find ADR's in standard accounts.